# Getting campaign stats (e.g. Clicks, CTR, CPC, etc.) via AdWords API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

What I'm trying to currently do is fetch Campaign statistics such as Clicks, Impressions, CTR, Average CPC and etc for a particular campaign. Unfortunately, I can't find how to do it via the AdWords API.

What I've found up till now is that,

1. Maybe, in an earlier version of the `CampaignService`, we were able to obtain stats by doing something like `$campaign->campaignStats`. Unluckily, I'm using `V201506` and in it there is no `campaignStats` object/variable.
2. I probably can get these stats using the '**CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT**' but it needs to be downloaded and I don't want to download the report. I just want an array or something similar returned so that I can process it. Also, I don't want to give any time frame, I just want all time stats to be returned for that campaign. Is it even possible?

If any one could help me out, I would really appreciate it. Kind of been stuck here for a few hours, skimmed through the whole AdWords API documentation but couldn't understand what would be the best and easy approach to this.

Answer (score 2):

Now, `Adwords API` allowing stats only By reporting service.
And stats can be get using two methods.

> 1) By using reporting service as described
>   [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report)
>
> 2) You can use Adwords Query Language. [See
>   this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql)

Comment: How can you get the cost with AWQL and CampaignService?

Comment: Indeed - how do you get the cost (or other fields) using AWQL - can you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you still need this but the API V201806 I found a solution. In this version of API exist the function getAsString() which returns the data in String and not download file, I request data in format XML and in PHP transform the response into a XML Object.

This is code I used:

```
class DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql {

public static function runExample(AdWordsSession $session, $reportFormat){

    // Create report query to get the data for last 7 days.
    $query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
        ->select([
            'CampaignId',
            'AdGroupId',
            'Id',
            'Criteria',
            'CriteriaType',
            'Impressions',
            'Clicks',
            'Cost',
            'Conversions'
        ])
        ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
        ->where('Status')->in(['ENABLED'])
        ->duringDateRange(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::LAST_7_DAYS)
        ->build();
    // Download report as a string.
    $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
    // Optional: If you need to adjust report settings just for this one
    // request, you can create and supply the settings override here.
    // Otherwise, default values from the configuration
    // file (adsapi_php.ini) are used.
    $reportSettingsOverride = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())->includeZeroImpressions(false)->build();

    $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReportWithAwql(
        sprintf('%s', $query),
        $reportFormat,
        $reportSettingsOverride
    );
    //print "Report was downloaded and printed below:\n";
    $datos = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
    return ($datos);
}
public static function main(){
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();
    // See: AdWordsSessionBuilder for setting a client customer ID that is
    // different from that specified in your adsapi_php.ini file.
    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the
    // OAuth2 credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();
    $string = self::runExample($session, DownloadFormat::XML);
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($string);
    return $xml;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked in 2015, since then they renamed the API to **Google Ads API**. The current version is **V6** where getting clicks, CTR, CPC and other metrics is relatively simple.

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v6/campaign) states:

> This page shows all metrics and segments that can be put in the same SELECT clause as the fields of campaign

Based on that the AWQL for getting campaign together with clicks will look like this (tested):

```
$query = "SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.status, metrics.clicks FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.name"
```

Example in PHP how to iterate through results:

```
$stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream($customerId, $query);

    foreach ($stream->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
        /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */

        $data['campaigns'][] = [
            'id'     => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getId(),
            'clicks' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks(),
        ];
    }
```